# Authenticate with a backend server

Tags: authentication, social-networking, backend, serve

Does anyone can help me to get a solution for Authenticate with a backend server, I need to find the best way to use the information(name,profile photo,email) from Facebook / twitter / google plus for Authenticate with my server.

After a long research I came to some conclusions. I would be happy if you can give me the directions to the right way to Authenticate with my backend server.

conclusions -

1. When user connects, keep all the information I needed in the serve and use him all the time
2. When user connects, keep only the user_id of him and when another user is looking for information about this user search in one of the social networks details about the user_id

I would appraise if you help me to get to the proper answer of this task.

Thanks

Comment: Track local the user id. Get user details over API from FB, ... - You can also use OAUTH

Comment: And actually keep all the users data on the server ?